# Array in C (Beginner) - My output are different from the answer

Tags: arrays, c

My code doesn't produce the desired output, i still don't know why. Can you help me with this. Thank you!

> The problem:
> Calculate the total monthly payment and the difference from the initial loan amount for a fixed-rate mortgage.
> A person wants to buy a house in Hanoi and has accepted a fixed-rate mortgage from a bank for an initial loan amount of m with an annual interest rate of r% for a duration of d years. Each month, the buyer will have to pay both the principal and the interest as follows:
> The fixed monthly principal payment will be m / (d * 12).
> The monthly interest payment will be calculated based on the remaining principal amount.For the first month, it will be (m * r / 12).
> For the following months, it will be ((m - m / (d * 12)) * r / 12), and so on, decreasing over time.

> Please write a program that takes the initial loan amount, the fixed interest rate, and the loan duration as input and prints on the screen the total monthly payment over d years and the difference from the initial loan amount. The values should be displayed as floating-point numbers rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
INPUT 
1000000000 0.11 10 
OUTPUT 
1554583333.33 554583333.33
```

This is my solution, but the outputs differ from the answers' several last numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long int money;
    double rate;
    int year;
    
    scanf("%lld %lf %d", &money, &rate, &year);
    
    double fixed_money=money/(year*12);
    double total_money=0;
    double a[year*12];

    for( int i=0; i< year*12; i++){
        a[i]= fixed_money+(money-i*fixed_money)*rate/12;
        total_money+=a[i];
    }
    
    printf("%.2lf %.2lf", total_money, total_money-money );
}
```

the ouputs are:

```
1554583315.15 554583315.15
```

Comment: There's just no need for an array here. Or a variable `a` at all. You could just do `total_money += fixed_money+(money-i*fixed_money)*rate/12;`

Comment: As a *possible* hint about the problem, remember that `money/(year*12)` is an integer operation. The division will not give you any decimals. Change `12` to `12.0` to fix that.

Comment: @ScottHunter The last line of the question appears to be their actual output. The expected output is before the code.

Comment: Fixing the integer division yields the correct answer.

Comment: Another way to fix the problem is to change the type of the variable `money` from `long long int` to `double` and change the `scanf` format string accordingly.

Comment: You don't really need the array for this problem because the old values in the array are never reused. You could declare `a` as `double a;` and replace `a[i]` with `a`.

Answer (score 3):

The key issue is that `money/(year*12)` is an integer division and so the `fixed_money` has a value of 8333333.0 with final output:

```
1554583315.15 554583315.15
```

Using `1.0*money/(year*12)`, or the like, the quotient is 8333333.33333... and the final output:

```
1554583333.33 554583333.33
```

Yet this is wrong too as the monthly payment needs to be rounded to the nearest cent or 8333333.33 with a final output:

```
1554583333.15 554583333.15
```